# Overflow within a fixed element

Tags: html, dom, css

I've got a problem with a fixed element and his child, which don't want to have a scrollbar and trying to get out from the parent element. You can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/NFV36/.

```
<div id="documents-popup">
  <div id="documents-popup-inner">
    <div class="controls">Something here which is always visible. And no one knows what height could it be...</div>
    <div class="list-wrap"> 
        <ul class="selector">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>Why are you looking at me? I shoud not be visible until you scroll all the way down...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the `selector` list scrollable, with a height less than (`#documents-popup-inner` + `.controls`) height no matter of the page's height. I know, how to make that with a JS, but is there any CSS solution?

Comment: I am not saying this is the best/only solution, but just trying to check if [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/NFV36/1/) is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Harry, yea, I want it look like this, but I don't know what height would have the green div (`controls`), so putting an accurate numbers will lead to some broken interface, if there will be more than one line. And btw, when you change the page height - `controls` height is not changing, so `%` is not an option too. But as an example of what I'm trying to do - this is good one.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/NFV36/7/

Comment: @asharajay as I said, when you change page height - `controls` height is not changing, so putting a 80% will lead to some visual errors on page resize. And I want to have only the list scrolled..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

?

Comment: Well I've tried to use all of the `overflow` combinations. The `scroll` will always show the bar, which is acceptable, but this is not the answer to my question.. I've wanted to make an JSless solution, which will show popup window properly on any resolution and window sizes..